# How can users translate documents using Word Online Preview?

Tags: microsoft-translator

This functionality used to exist for guests of a document but seems to be missing in the latest version of Word Online.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please direct this question to the Microsoft Office support team at https://support.office.com/en-us/word. At the bottom of the page you can choose to ask for Office or community support.

Best regards,
Gwenda
Microsoft Translator Team